# nuget.config package source add <clear /> with command line parameter?

Tags: .net-core, nuget

For my nuget.config, I need the `<clear />` configuration on my `<packageSources>` like this

```
<packageSources>
  <clear />
  <add key="MyNexusNuGit" value="URL_TO_NEXUS_GIT" />
</packageSources>
```

I am also trying to automate configuration. I have this command line which will add the the source to nuget.config, but I don't see any option or command line parameter to add `<clear />`

```
dotnet nuget add source "URL_TO_NEXUS_NUGET" --name "MyNexusNuGet" --username USER --password "PASS"
```

Does anyone know if there is a command line option or parameter to automate adding `<clear />` to the nuget.config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a new `nuget.config` file using `dotnet new nugetconfig` command.

This generates a new file with the following content that already includes a `<clear>` tag.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear/> line below -->
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Next, add the new package source using below command.

```bash
dotnet nuget add source "http://packageSourceUrl.com" --name "MyNexusNuGet" --username USER --password "PASS" --configfile "C:\Users\ankushzn\nuget.config"
```

This will add the new package source in the XML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear/> line below -->
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="MyNexusNuGet" value="http://packageSourceUrl.com" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <MyNexusNuGet>
        <add key="Username" value="USER" />
        <add key="Password" value="AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAATo.......=" />
      </MyNexusNuGet>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your simple but great answer!